# Not able to send keys to field in chrome(In firefox same code is working)

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, protractor

HTML code

```
    <textarea type="text" name="pos_description" rows="4" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-minlength ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" id="pos_description" placeholder="Enter Description" ng-model="data.description" minlength="150" maxlength="5000" required="">
   </textarea>
```

My code

```
 browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,250);');
 browser.sleep(3000);
 element(by.model('textarea.data.description')).sendKeys("values");
```

I am getting the error as below:-

> StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not
>   attached to the page do
>
> cument
>
> (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.132)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.15.322448
>   (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Linux
>   3.13.0-55-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 45 milliseconds

Please help me

Comment: Can you update your chrome browser to the latest version and check if you still get this error? Also what version of protractor and selenium webdriver are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This could be mostly because of the page not loaded properly. The Page might have loaded but some Elements in the page might load, disappear out of the page for a fraction of second and then load again. So when the page is loaded, the text area is found by Selenium and by the time it tries to click, the Element might have reloaded.

Put a try catch [Java] equivalent in protractor to catch the Exception and find the element again and click for the second time.

```
try {
     element(by.model('textarea.data.description')).sendKeys("values");
} catch (StaleElementReferenceError e) {
     element(by.model('textarea.data.description')).sendKeys("values");
}
```

I dont know of this is possible in Protractor. If not you can always increase the sleep time.

Answer (score 0):

Your html looks like this:   ng-model="data.description" 
but you're doing this: element(by.model('textarea.data.description'))

It should be:  element(by.model('data.description'))